# what is reason for bringing tools:context in parent layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

Android studio adds `tools:context` line by default in layouts which are created for fragments and activities and place it in parent layout of activity/fragment.

I want to know what is usage and will it cause any problem in child layouts if I remove this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tools support's attribute that enable design-time features like tools:context =".Mainactivity" would tell which layout the current xml belongs to. If you want to show a placeholder of your ui with sample data that is available only at design time - say display a list with each row having a image - you could use the available tools attribute and see how the list view looks at design time without having to actually run the app. Its only for design and it does not affect when you run the app.

Some more info on the same https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.

> I want to know what is usage and will it cause any problem in child
>   layouts if I remove this line?

Should be fine. Nothing to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Anything in the `tools` namespace has no effect on runtime. It's simply there so the IDE knows what is supposed to happen and the Design View can show sample data.

The `tools:context` field follows the same logic.

You might know about the `android:onCick` field in XML for Views, where you can do something like:

```
<View
    android:onClick="someFunction"
/>
```

This is where the `context` field comes in. If you remove that field and have XML-defined `onClick` functions, the IDE will complain that `someFunction` isn't defined. It'll compile just fine, but the IDE has no way of knowing whether or not that function actually exists in the parent Activity unless you use the `tools:context` field.